# Why are two conditions needed for a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the definition of a linear transformation, we have:

\begin{align}
    f(ax) &= af(x) \\
    f(x + y) &= f(x) + f(y)
\end{align}

Isn't equation (2) just enough for this definition?

If the answer is NO, can you show an example that there must be equation (1) in the definition?

Comment: How could (2) imply (1)?

Comment: You should pay attention to which variables represent vectors and which represent constants in your equation.

Comment: $a$ is a scalar (number). $x$ is a vector. When $a$ is a positive integer, only then can $1$ follow from $2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: we consider the one- dimensional vectorspace $V:= \mathbb C$ over the field $ \mathbb C$ and the mapping $f:V \to V$ given by

$$f(z)= \overline {z}.$$

We have

$$f(z+w)=f(z)+f(w),$$

but

$$f(az)=\overline{a}f(z).$$

If $ a \notin \mathbb R$, then $f(az) \ne a f(z).$

Comment: Can we say , equation 1 is written to be true for the complex coefficients?

Comment: Equation 1 is false if $a \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R.$

Comment: Thank you so much